# Linked List IPC C Language

Tags: c, linux, linked-list, ipc, daemon

Im making simple service with daemon to sniff internet packets from any ip. I faced with the problem, that i don't know how to store Linked List of IP's and their count of packets to another proccess(cli) from daemon proccess(where i store them in linked list). I surfed internet for information and find that i should use IPC like shared memory, pipe/fifo, pair socket and etc. But i don't get how to work with any of those to send FULL linked list to CLI. Can you please tell me, which case of IPC i should use for my task? And how EXACTLY to transfer LINKED LIST via of any.

*The main point - is make cli which can interact with my daemon.*

**Struct of linked list:**

```
typedef struct s_ip
{
        uint64_t address;
        size_t packets;
        struct s_ip *next;
}               t_ip;
```

I can store via shared memory only single variable like char* but nothing other, like linked list or malloced array of structs

Also, should i use array of structs instead of linked list to transfer data to another proccess?

If it's possible, give me the example like this:

**DAEMON**

```
/* Daemon code side */
void sendlist_daemon(t_ip *ip_list)
{
    /* code that store linked list */
}
```

**CLI**

```
/* CLI code side */
t_ip *getlist_cli(void)
{
    t_ip *ip_list;

    ip_list = /* here i can get list */
    return (ip_list);
}
```

*Notice: Daemon always listening for packets so i decided to make linked list and just push elements with incoming packets. But sometimes, when user from cli request info about all packets from all ips i must send them to him.*

Thanks.

Comment: You have to send the entire list one item at a time using a loop; prior to that you should send the count of items you are sending OR have the cli keep reading until a marker of some sort.

Comment: Use a data structure that doesn't involve pointers, or a message queue or datagram Unix domain socket and send one item at a time.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please note that asking us to fill in, essentially an empty template does not fall within [mcve] guide lines.   I suggest that you work on that first (e.g. where's the code to send a single item?)

Comment: This is actually prerry simple. Just use `fprintf(stream, "%" PRIu64 " %zu\n", it->address, it->packets)"` to send and on the receiving side `fcntl(fileno(stream), O_NONBLOCK); while (poll({fileno(STREAM), POLLIN, ....)) { new = malloc(...); fscanf(f, "%" PRIu64 " %zu\n", &new->address, &new->packets); last->next = new; last=new; }`

Comment: @KamilCuk should it work when daemon don't know when exactly CLI need this list? And also daemon don't know CLI launched or not.

Comment: A good code would handle all the cases. That's why the call to poll - so you can set timeout. Also you should handle all malformed inputs and all possible invalid values.

Comment: Be aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR). It is relevant. Read also carefully [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't transfer `Next` address. It's irrelevant. Transfer only information needed. You need to establish the format of data which will you use. What endianess will you use? What bit is first, MSB first or LSB first? What character set will you use? Binary stream or readable text? Separated by a special character or not separated? Compression? Encryption? Which compression? Which encryption? And finally, how are the data formatted? How to handle errors? And finally, how will the api look like? Should it take FILE pointer, file descriptor number, platform dependent input/output handle or function pointers? Those are question engineers answer when designing systems.

The best is to stay as portable as possible (`size_t` is not so much portable, but i left it).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct s_ip
{
        uint64_t address;
        size_t packets;
        struct s_ip *next;
} ip_t;

#define IP_LIST_INIT() {0}

void ip_list_elem_init(ip_t *elem, uint64_t address, size_t packets)
{
    elem->address = address;
    elem->packets = packets;
    elem->next = NULL;
}

int ip_list_add(ip_t **head, uint64_t address, size_t packets)
{
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = malloc(sizeof(**head));
        if (*head == NULL) return -__LINE__;
        ip_list_elem_init(*head, address, packets);
    } else {
        ip_t *i;
        for (i = *head; i->next != NULL; i = i->next) {
            continue;
        }
        i->next = malloc(sizeof(*i->next));
        if (i->next == NULL) return -__LINE__;
        ip_list_elem_init(i->next, address, packets);
    }
    return 0;
}

void ip_list_free(ip_t *head)
{
    // use system deallocator.... :)
    return;
}

int ip_list_send(ip_t *head, FILE *f)
{
    char start_of_text = '\x02'; // STX START_OF_TEXT ascii character
    char end_of_text = '\x03'; // ETX END_OF_TEXT ascii character

    if (fprintf(f, "%c\n", start_of_text) < 0) return -__LINE__;

    size_t tmp = 0;
    for (ip_t *i = head; i != NULL; i = i->next) {
        tmp++;
    }
    if (fprintf(f, "%zu\n", tmp) < 0) return -__LINE__;

    for (ip_t *i = head; i != NULL; i = i->next) {
        if (fprintf(f, "%" PRIu64 " %zu\n", i->address, i->packets) < 0) return -__LINE__;
    }

    if (fprintf(f, "%c\n", end_of_text) < 0) return -__LINE__;

    return 0;
}

int ip_list_recv(ip_t **head, FILE *f)
{
    if (fcntl(fileno(f), F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0) return -__LINE__;

    enum {
        START_TEXT,
        READING_COUNT,
        READING_ELEMS,
        STOP_TEXT,
        END,
    } state = START_TEXT;

    size_t cnt = 0;
    ip_t *prev = NULL;

    while (state != END) {
        struct pollfd pfd = { .fd = fileno(f), .events = POLLIN };
        int pollret = poll(&pfd, 1, 100);
        if (pollret < 0) return -__LINE__;
        if (pollret == 0) break;
        if (pfd.revents != POLLIN) return -__LINE__;

        switch (state) {
        case START_TEXT: {
            char c;
            if (fscanf(f, "%c\n", &c) != 1) return -__LINE__; // start of transmission
            if (c != '\x02') return -__LINE__;
            state = READING_COUNT;
            break;
        }
        case READING_COUNT: {
            if (fscanf(f, "%zu\n", &cnt) != 1) return -__LINE__;
            state = READING_ELEMS;
            break;
        }
        case READING_ELEMS: {
            ip_t *next = malloc(sizeof(*next));
            if (next == NULL) return -__LINE__;
            if (fscanf(f, "%" SCNu64 " %zu\n", &next->address, &next->packets) != 2) return -__LINE__;
            ip_list_elem_init(next, next->address, next->packets);
            if (prev) {
                prev->next = next;
            } else {
                *head = next;
            }
            prev = next;
            cnt--;
            if (cnt == 0) {
                state = STOP_TEXT;
            }
            break;
        }
        case STOP_TEXT: {
            char c;
            if (fscanf(f, "%c\n", &c) != 1) return -__LINE__;
            if (c != '\x03') return -__LINE__; // end of transmission
            state = END;
            break;
        }
        default:
            assert(0);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void ip_list_print(ip_t *head)
{
    for (ip_t *i = head; i != NULL; i = i->next) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%p %" PRIu64 " %zu\n", (void*)i, i->address, i->packets);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
}

int main() 
{
    int ret;


    FILE *f = tmpfile();
    if (!f) return -__LINE__;

    {
        printf("Sending side:\n");
        ip_t *head = IP_LIST_INIT();
        if (ip_list_add(&head, 1, 1)) return -__LINE__;
        if (ip_list_add(&head, 2, 2)) return -__LINE__;
        if (ip_list_add(&head, 3, 3)) return -__LINE__;
        ip_list_print(head);
        if ((ret = ip_list_send(head, f))) return ret;
        ip_list_free(head);
    }

    rewind(f);

    {
        printf("Receiving side:\n");
        ip_t *head = IP_LIST_INIT();
        if ((ret = ip_list_recv(&head, f))) return -ret;
        ip_list_print(head);
        ip_list_free(head);
    }
}
```

One side just serializes the list using simple `fprintf` calls in `ip_list_send`. First it sends the ASCII character '\x02' which is called `START OF TEXT` with a newline. Then the count of elements it will write written in ASCII characters with a newline. Then for each elem the element with a newline. On the end '\x03' is transferred ie. `END OF TEXT` with a newline.

`ip_list_recv` deserializes data. It uses a simple state machine to remember the state it is in, tracks the count and allocates memory, uses fscanf to read the data. The code has probably tons of bugs, malicious attackers can use it. The `poll` call in this code is mostly useless, it's called only after newlines, serves as a seed of good code. Good code should read a line into a buffer by calling `poll` after each read character and `fgetc` or better `read(..., 1)` to read a single character at a time and add it to buffer, and all the calls to `fscanf` could be `sscanf(line, ...)`. Probably also implementing a global/function scope parameter specified timeout for the function would be nice. Also one could rewrite the functions to use file descriptors and use `fdopen(fd, ...)` with `fclose()` when a file pointer is needed for `fprintf`.

Comment: Really nice answer, however not sure if you need to implement a read single char at a time for "secure code".